# bash permission denied but sh works

Tags: bash, shell-script

A little script of mine on a mounted windows partition refuses to be executed directly (shebang is `#!/bin/bash`), but interestingly calling it with `bash`/`sh` works. The script is simply a collection of `grep` and `sed` commands.

The drive is mounted with full rights:

```
defaults,windows_names,rw,auto,user
```

Hence, for the the file got

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root
```

for the file.

What's going on there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most probably the windows partition is mounted with the `noexec` flag on. You can confirm in the output of:

```
mount
```

In the output you will probably see something like `(rw,noexec)` at the end of the line. The `noexec` flag is not a default, so this usually happens when it is configured explicitly to mount it that way.

When you run the script with `bash /path/to/script.sh` it works,
because in that case you're executing not the script, 
but you're executing `bash`, which interprets the script given in its argument.

As an additional note:

> but interestingly calling it with sh works.

Since the script has the shebang `#!/bin/bash`, you should use `bash` instead of `sh` to execute it. The author of the script probably used this shebang for a reason, and some implementations of `sh` (or whatever it's linked to in your system) may not support some Bash features.

Finally,
to be able to execute the script directly,
you *could* try to mount the drive with `exec` flag instead of `noexec`,
but first think about whether that's really a good idea or not.
The default of mounting with `noexec` is for a safety feature,
to prevent accidental execution of potentially harmful files coming from untrusted sources. I don't think you should change that. Just run with `bash`.

Comment: I added the line with which I mount the drive to the question. I do not specify the `noexec` option, but I am not sure whether it is maybe included in one of the other options.

Comment: Run the `mount` command and find the line of the mount point. I bet it has `noexec` written on it. If you mount the drive manually, you can specify the `exec` flag explicitly. But as I explained, I don't recommend to do that.

Comment: Okay, then I'll leave it at it's current state and will run my scripts with `sh`/`bash`.

Comment: @MERose - the `user` option implies `noexec`. From `man mount` *user:   Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the mounting user is written to `mtab` (or to the private `libmount` file in  `/run/mount`  on  system  without  regular `mtab`)  so that he can `unmount` the filesystem again.  This option  implies  the  options `noexec`, `nosuid`, and `nodev` (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line `user,exec,dev,suid`).*